# How can I test the type of query Mongoid will generate?

Tags: rspec, tdd, mongoid

I'm trying to assert, using RSpec, that a given Mongoid query will **not** load the record, just check for its existence, because the record is big (several MB), and the code needs to only know whether or not the record exists.

I've been playing with `.exists?` on associations, but for some reason that doesn't seem to work with `has_one` such as:

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document

  has_one :chart
end

class Chart  # this is heavy
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :profile
end

profile.chart.exists?  # fails if chart returns nil
```

The `exists?` proxy method apparently doesn't work for `has_one` relationships; although it's documented for `has_many`. I want to craft my own, but I need to test in RSpec that indeed the record is only queried not loaded. I'm thinking about doing something like testing for the underlying query being generated to the Mongo driver, like you can do with `.to_sql`.  Is there a corresponding Mongoid method?

Comment: You'll probably want to stub the part of Mongoid that handles transformation of a BSON response into a document, then ensure that it's not called.

Comment: Got a code snippet for me? I was more hoping for something analogous to .to_sql in Arel. I'm sure it's there somewhere deep down in Moped.

Comment: I don't know Mongoid/Moped that well, unfortunately (I maintain MongoMapper). If you want a to_sql equivalent, you're going to want to look at your `Mongoid::Criteria` before it's transformed into the document. The trick will be getting your hands on that before the criteria is actually run as a query.

Comment: Exactly. I haven't dove into the nitty gritty either. I don't know if it's coded for this purposes and offers the right access points.

Comment: Well, in fairness, Ruby basically always offers the right access points. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
profile.chart.nil?
```

doesn't work?

Comment: How does this help me write a test case that the object isn't loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [command monitoring](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-monitoring/#command-monitoring) in the driver to inspect actual queries sent to the database. This works for queries that return no results also (since the query is sent regardless).